# In quantum process tomography, how does $\chi$ characterize a quantum process?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-process-tomography

I'm working through Nielsen and Chuang and I'm pretty confused by the discussion of quantum process tomography. I'm trying to work through an example of 1-qubit state tomography given by N&C (box 8.5), which provides an algorithm for determining $\chi$ in terms of block matrices and density matrices (determined by state tomography). The process seems pretty straight forward, but how does $\chi$ characterize a quantum process?

Comment: See also the answer to [How to perform Quantum Process Tomography for three qubit gates?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/how-to-perform-quantum-process-tomography-for-three-qubit-gates). It describes in length the $\chi$ matrix; if you still have doubts, could you clarify what exactly you don't find clear about it?)

Comment: Thank you, I have read that Q&A previously, and the wikipedia page is references. I think my confusion is more fundamental. What I'm not clear on is this: given a chi matrix, what does it concretely tell me about a quantum process? For example, if I try to characterize a process on one qubit, how do I know my chi matrix is correct?

Comment: I'm afraid that I still don't fully understand the question. Are you familiar with Kraus operators? There is a very strong correlation between the eigen-values and -vectors of the $\chi$ matrix of a quantum channel, and a Kraus representation of the channel - and a particular nice representation. The eigenvectors are basically the coefficients of the Kraus operators decomposed into the basis used for the $\chi$ matrix. If this is something you are looking for in an answer, I can write one and elaborate a bit further?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kraus operators unfortunately. Can the quantum operation itself be deduced from the chi matrix? I'm a beginner (clearly), so thanks for the patience with this!

Comment: Do you mean with _quantum operation_ a unitary (operation) that I perform on the qubit? The term _quantum operation_ is  somewhat more general in that it applies also to the more general quantum channels - of which unitary operations are a subset.

Comment: Yes, I am considering only unitary transformations. I am trying to get a grasp of QPT for simple unitary transformations on one qubit.

Comment: also related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11814/55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear map $\mathcal{E}$ is what characterizes a quantum process,

$$\rho \rightarrow \mathcal{E}(\rho),$$

but $\mathcal{E}$ can be determined by $\chi$. Using the operator-sum representation,

$$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \sum_i A_i \rho A^\dagger_i = \sum_{i}\sum_{m}\sum_{n}a_{im}\tilde{A}_m \rho a^*_{in}\tilde{A}^\dagger_n,$$

where the $a_{ij}$ are some set of complex numbers that allow a *fixed* set of operators $\tilde{A}_{i}$ to form a basis for the unknown set of operators $A_i$ on the state space. Remember, if we can determine the operators $A_i$, then we can completely describe $\mathcal{E}$. Rearranging the above,

$$\mathcal{E}(\rho) = \sum_m \sum_n \tilde{A}_m \rho \tilde{A}^\dagger_n \sum_i a_{im} a^*_{in} = \sum_{mn} \tilde{A}_m \rho \tilde{A}^\dagger_n \chi_{mn},$$

where $\chi_{mn}$ is a "classical" *error correlation matrix*, which is positive Hermitian by definition. So, once the set of operators $\tilde{A}_i$ has been fixed, $\mathcal{E}$ can be determined completely by the complex number matrix $\chi$.$^{\text{[1]}}$

Note: The adjective "fixed" does not apply to any of the operators themselves, rather, it applies to the set of operators. The point is that the operators $A_i$ are unknown, so we are writing the $A_i$ in terms of a basis of known operators $\tilde{A}_i$ that we have chosen. The problem of determining the $A_i$ thus reduces to the problem of determining the coefficients $a_{ij}$ in this basis. This is not any different from determining an unknown vector by writing the vector as a linear combination of a fixed set of basis vectors, then finding the coefficients in this basis.

[1] *Prescription for experimental determination of the dynamics of a quantum black box*, Isaac L. Chuang, M. A. Nielson, 2008. https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9610001

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Given a process matrix $\chi$ expressed in a normalized, ordered Pauli basis $\{P^{n}_{k}\}$, find its eigendecomposition $\{\lambda_{i},\mathbf{v_{i}}\}$, where $0 \leq \lambda_{i} \leq 1$ and $\mathbf{v_{i}} = (v^{i}_{P^{n}_{k}})$ is the eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ and contains 'coefficients' for every Pauli $P^{n}_{k}$. $\chi$ is Hermitian, so the $\lambda_{i}$'s are real and nonnegative, and the eigenvectors from different eigenvalues are orthogonal.

**If the map represented by the process matrix is unitary** there will be only one nonzero eigenvalue, let's call it $\lambda_{0}$ (then $\lambda_{0} = 1$). The corresponding eigenvector is then just the unitary $U$ expressed in the Pauli basis. We can readily compute $U$:

$$
U = \sum_{k} v^{0}_{P^{n}_{k}}P^{n}_{k}
$$

For a single qubit, the $\chi$ matrix is  $4 \times 4$ matrix. If again it represents a unitary channel, we get a single nonzero eigenvalue equal to one, and its corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{v} = (v_{I},v_{X},v_{Y},v_{Z})$. Then, the single-qubit unitary represented by the map is:

$$
U = \sum_{P} v_{P}P = v_{I}I + v_{X}X + v_{Y}Y + v_{Z}Z.
$$
Note that the $v_{P}$ are in general complex numbers.

If the map is supposed to be unitary, but it has a bit of noise in it, this will be reflected by one eigenvalue being close to $1$, corresponding to the unitary operation, and some (or all) other eigenvalues being small but nonzero - these correspond to the noise operators.

### Density matrices and maps?

In its most general form, a quantum state is described not by a single ket state (e.g. $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$, but by a *statistical mixture* of kets (e.g. $\{p_{i},|\psi_{i}\rangle\}$ described the situation that we have state $|\psi_{i}\rangle$ with probability $p_{i}$). If there is just one nonzero $p_{i}$, we get a single ket state back, and we call this state a *pure* state. Any other state is also referred to as a *mixed* state.

It turns out that we can - and it is **extremely** useful - to write this as a sum of outer products $\sum_{i}p_{i} |\psi_{i}\rangle\langle \psi_{i}|$. We call this the *density matrix* $\rho$ and, as mentioned before, this is the most general description that we can have of a quantum system. As a general rule of thumb, in quantum computing we always *want*

For pure states, the operations that we perform on them are *gates*, represented by *unitary matrices*. We can also apply these to density matrices, but there are also different valid operations that we can apply to density matrices. Any such operation we call a *quantum operation* or *quantum channel*, which is a linear map $\rho_{in} \rightarrow \Lambda(\rho_{in}) = \rho_{out}$ which is subject to some constraints to make sure that $\rho_{out}$ is a valid density matrix - I won't go into them here.

To fully characterize this $\Lambda$, there are multiple different representations - one of which is the *process matrix* $\chi$. In QPT, it is the goal to characterize a unknown map $\Lambda$ by finding one if its representations, where often the $\chi$ matrix is used. These can also represent unitary channels, but they can represent more.