# What is the relationship between Choi and Chi matrix in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-operation, state-tomography, quantum-process-tomography

I'm struggling with the framework for quantum process tomography on Qiskit.

The final step of such a framework is running `fit` method of `ProcessTomographyFitter` class. Documentation states that such function gives a Choi matrix as output. Nevertheless, I'd want the Chi matrix to define the superoperator of a circuit. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how a 2-qubit circuit affects a single qubit.

**Thus, my questions are:**

- What is the relationship between Choi and Chi matrix?
- When do they coincide?
- How to obtain Chi from Choi matrix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Quantum Process Tomography for three qubit gates?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/how-to-perform-quantum-process-tomography-for-three-qubit-gates)

Comment: I feel that that question is not a complete answer to this question, as it does not describe how to obtain the chi matrix from the Choi matrix or when they are the same.

Comment: So do I. Anyway it answers partially. Thus, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

( I copied some text from a [previous answer of mine)](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11622/how-to-perform-quantum-process-tomography-for-three-qubit-gates/11691#11691)

### Defining the Choi and $\chi$ matrix

The [*Choi* matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps) is a direct result of the Choi-Jamiolkowski isomorphism. Some intuition on what this is can be found [in this previous answer by Norbert Schuch](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11580/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-choi-jamiolkowski-of-a-quantum-channel/11624#11624). Consider the maximally entangled state $|\Omega \rangle = \sum_{\mathrm{i}}|\mathrm{i}\rangle \otimes |\mathrm{i}\rangle$, where $\{|\mathrm{i}\rangle\}$ forms a basis for the space on which $\rho$ acts. (Note that we thus have a maximally entangled state of twice as many qubits).
The Choi matrix is the state that we get when on one of these subsystems $\Lambda$ is applied (leaving the other subsystem intact):
\begin{equation}
\rho_{\mathrm{Choi}} = \big(\Lambda \otimes I\big) |\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|.
\end{equation}
As the Choi matrix is a state, it must be positive semidefinite (corresonding the the CP constraint) and must have unit trace (necessary but not sufficient for the TP constraint).

The [*process*- or $\chi$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tomography#Standard_quantum_process_tomography) comes from the fact that we can write our map as a double sum:
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(\rho) = \sum_{m,n} \chi_{mn}P_{m}\rho P_{n}^{\dagger},
\end{equation}
where $\{P_{m}\}$ & $\{P_{n}\}$ form a basis for the space of density matrices; we use the Pauli basis $\{I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n}$ (thereby omitting the need for the $\dagger$ at $P_{n}$). The matrix $\chi$ now encapsulates all information of $\Lambda$; the CP constraint reads that $\chi$ must be positive semidefinite, and the trace constraint reads that $\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}P_{n}P_{m} \leq I$ (with equality for TP).

### Computing one from another

From this, we get the following two identities:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho_{\mathrm{Choi}} &= \sum_{m,n} \chi_{m,n} |P_{m}\rangle\rangle\langle\langle P_{n}|, \\
\chi_{m,n} &= \langle\langle P_{m} | \rho_{\mathrm{Choi}} |P_{n}\rangle\rangle,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $|P_{m}\rangle\rangle$ is the 'vectorized' version of $P_{m}$, which is essentially just the columns of $P_{m}$ stacked on top of each other, giving a vector. That answers question 3.

Again I shamelessly 'self-promote': in the first appendix of [my thesis](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A39258a70-a347-40bb-a2f9-9ca301a71652?collection=education) I work through proofs of all these relations. The most intuitive way is by using the Kraus decomposition as an intermediary, but it is not needed.

### Relationship between the two

From this, you can see that the Choi matrix and the chi matrix do indeed have some relationship. In fact, by choosing either the (qubit)-basis in which we express the Choi matrix, or choosing the (operator)-basis that we associate with the $\chi$-matrix, they can be one and the same.

As @AdamZalcman has pointed out in his comment (Thank you!), from the identity $\chi_{m,n} = \langle \langle P_{m}|\rho_{\mathrm{Choi}}| P_{n}\rangle\rangle$ we can choose the $P_{m/n}$ so that we just select the $m$-th row and $n$-th column of $\rho_{\mathrm{Choi}}$. This works if $P_{k} = |i\rangle \langle j|$, with $k = id + j$. Since both $i$ and $j$ run from $0$ to $d-1$ (indicating the column and row, respectively), this gives exactly $d^{2}$ elements.

The same effect can be reached if one expresses the Choi matrix in a different basis, while keeping the $P_{k}$ associated with $\chi_{m,n}$ the usual Paulis. For the two to coincide then (i.e. $\chi_{m,n} = \rho_{\mathrm{Choi}}^{m,n}$), we see that $\rho_{\mathrm{Choi}}^{m,n}$ should be expressed in the `vectorized-Pauli-basis' (which is a set of states, i.e. a basis for the Hilbert space!) - this is exactly the Bell basis.

Comment: Thank you! What I believe is missing now is how all this math behind QPT and Quantum Channels is applied in Qiskit. The Qiskit's method works with Pauli basis, and it returns a Choi-matrix, but it seems corresponding to a Chi-matrix.

Speaking more in programming language, the method returns a Choi object that is a 4x4 matrix (since I'm interested in the superoperator from one qubit to one qubit for a 2-qubit circuit).

From documentation of the Chi object we have that Chi-matrix "is related to the Choi representation by a change of basis of the Choi-matrix into the Pauli basis".

Comment: You're welcome!I am not 100 percent sure what is the problem here anymore. The fit method indeed returns a Choi matrix (at least that is what it did when I used it ~1.5 years ago). If you want to have the chi matrix, you can just calculate it yourself using the equations I provided. Or, if you check the source code for the chi matrix class (https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/channel/chi.html), you can pass the Choi matrix to the init function as the 'data' variable; thereby obtaining the chi matrix for that channel.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer! I think the statement that the Choi matrix is the $\chi$ matrix when $P_k$ are the Bell basis rather than the Pauli basis is not correct. Note that as you wrote $\chi_{m,n} = \langle\langle P_m|\rho_{Choi}|P_n\rangle\rangle$ which means that for Choi and $\chi$ to coincide we need $P_k$ to vectorize to "one-hot" basis (aka standard basis). Consequently $P_k = |i\rangle\langle j|$ where $i$ and $j$ are determined by $k$ from $k=id + j$ where $d$ is Hilbert space dimension $i,j=0,1,\dots,d-1$ and $k=0,1,\dots,d^2-1$.

Comment: @AdamZalcman (A quite delayed) thanks for your comment! That was indeed quite sloppy of me - I'll update the text.