# How to derive the number of independent parameters in the $\chi$ matrix from the Choi matrix?

Tags: quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, kraus-representation, quantum-process-tomography

In the section on [Quantum process tomography, Page 391, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf). it is given that

> In general, $\chi$ will contain $d^4−d^2$ independent real parameters, because a general linear map of $d$ by $d$ complex matrices to $d$ by $d$ matrices is described by $d^4$ independent parameters, but there are $d^2$ additional constraints due to the fact that $\rho$ remains Hermitian with trace one; that is, the completeness relation $\sum_i E_i^\dagger E_i=I$ is satisfied, giving $d^2$ real constraints.

---

A post, [Why does the $\chi$ matrix have $d^4-d^2$ independent parameters?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28924/why-does-the-chi-matrix-have-d4-d2-independent-parameters/28927#28927), has been asked on this, which contains an answer by @DaftWullie, which make use of the Choi matrix,

[image: post]

where it seems like $\chi$ is used to represent the Choi matrix, not the $\chi$ matrix.

---

$\chi$ is a hermitian $d^2\times d^2$ matrix which must have $d^2$ diagonal real (independent) terms, and the number of terms below the diagonal is $\dfrac{(d^2-1)d^2}{2}$ that contains a total of $2\times\dfrac{(d^2-1)d^2}{2}=d^4-d^2$ of real terms. Therefore, the total number of independent real parameters considering only that $\chi$ is hermitian, is $(d^4-d^2)+d^2=d^4$.

---

The Choi matrix is given by, $\sigma=(I_R\otimes\mathcal{E})(|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha |)$ where $|\alpha\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i |i_R\rangle\otimes|i_Q\rangle$ is a maximally entangled state of the systems $R$ and $Q$.

$$
\sigma=(I_R\otimes\mathcal{E})(|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha |)=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_{i,j}|i_R\rangle\langle j_R|\otimes\mathcal{E}(|i_Q\rangle\langle j_Q|)
$$
which can be interpreted as the block matrix with $\frac{1}{d}\mathcal{E}(|i_Q\rangle\langle j_Q|)$ as the $(i,j)^{th}$ block.

The $\chi$ matrix is defined by setting $E_i=\sum_m e_{im}\tilde{E}_m$, with $\{\tilde{E}_m\}$ being any orthonormal basis for the set of operators on the state space, such that
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\sum_i E_i\rho E_i^\dagger=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}\tilde{E}_m\rho\tilde{E}_n^\dagger
$$
where the $(m,n)^{th}$ element of $\chi$ is $\chi_{mn}=\sum_i e_{im}e_{in}^*$ such that
$$
\chi=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}|m\rangle\langle n|
$$
$$
\sigma=(I_R\otimes\mathcal{E})(|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha |)=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}(I\otimes \tilde{E}_m)|\alpha\rangle\langle\alpha |(I\otimes \tilde{E}_n^\dagger)=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}|\tilde{E}_m\rangle\langle\tilde{E}_n|
$$
where
\begin{align}|\tilde{E}_m\rangle&=(I\otimes \tilde{E}_m)|\alpha\rangle\\
&=(I\otimes \tilde{E}_m)\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i |i_R\rangle\otimes|i_Q\rangle\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i |i_R\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|i_Q\rangle
\end{align}
and therefore
$$
\chi_{mn}=\langle\tilde{E}_m|\sigma|\tilde{E}_n\rangle
$$
Now, the Choi matrix can be written as,
\begin{align}
\sigma&=\sum_{m}(I\otimes {E}_m)(\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_{i,j}|i_R\rangle\langle j_R|\otimes|i_Q\rangle\langle j_Q|)(I\otimes {E}_m^\dagger)\\
&=\sum_{i,j}|i\rangle\langle j|\otimes\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger\\
\end{align}
Therefore, the $(i,j)^{th}$ block of the Choi matrix $\sigma$ is $\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger$.

The $(k,l)^{th}$ term of the $(i,j)^{th}$ block of the Choi matrix is,
$$
\sigma_{ij,kl}=\langle k|(\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger)|l\rangle\\
=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m\langle k|{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger|l\rangle\\
$$
$$
\sigma_{ij,kl}=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m\langle k|{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger|l\rangle
$$
We are free to choose $\tilde{E}_m=\sqrt{d}|t\rangle\langle q|$ such that $m=qd+t$ equates the Choi matrix and the $\chi$ matrix, therefore
$$
\boxed{\chi_{ij,kl}=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m\langle k|{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger|l\rangle}
$$

---

Applying the trace preserving condition, $\sum_m E_m^\dagger E_m=I\implies\sum_m \langle k|E_m^\dagger E_m|i\rangle=\delta_{ik}$

This much is clear!

Then it says,

This directly influences the $\chi$:
$$
\sum_j\chi_{ij,kj}=\delta_{ik}
$$
There are (complex) constraints for all $d^2$ values of $i,k$. However, since everything is Hermitian, again this corresponds to $d^2$ real constraints. Thus, the total freedom remaining is $d^4-d^2$.

> How do we obtain $\sum_j\chi_{ij,kj}=\delta_{ik}$ ?

> How does imposing the trace-preserving condition $\sum_m E_m^\dagger E_m=I$ on the Choi matrix obtains the number of constraints on the $\chi$ matrix ?

**My Attempt**

Thanks @JSdJ for the hint.

$\chi_{mn}=\langle\tilde{E}_m|\sigma|\tilde{E}_n\rangle\implies \sigma=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}|\tilde{E}_m\rangle\langle\tilde{E}_n|$

Therefore, in order for $\sigma=\chi$, we need $|\tilde{E}_m\rangle=|m\rangle$, where $m:0\to d^2-1$

$(I\otimes\tilde{E}_m)|\alpha\rangle=|\tilde{E}_m\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_i |i\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|i\rangle=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{d}}[|0\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|0\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|1\rangle+\cdots+|d^2-1\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|d^2-1\rangle]$

Let's consider the case when $d=2\implies d^2-1=3$,

Then,

where $\tilde{E}_m|i\rangle$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $\tilde{E}_m$,  ie., $|i\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|i\rangle$ is a column vector with the $i^{th}$ column of $\tilde{E}_m$ as it's $i^{th}$ block, all other elements are zero. So, $\sum_i |i\rangle\otimes\tilde{E}_m|i\rangle$ is the column vector with the columns of $\tilde{E}_m$ stacked on top of each other in order.

We can divide $|m\rangle$ into $d$ blocks of dimension $d$ such that let's take $m=qd+t$, where $q,t:0\to d-1$.

So, for $|\tilde{E}_m\rangle=|m\rangle$ we need to choose $\tilde{E}_m=\sqrt{d}|t\rangle\langle q|$, such that $\sigma=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}|\tilde{E}_m\rangle\langle\tilde{E}_n|=\sum_{m,n}\chi_{mn}|m\rangle\langle n|=\chi$

$\therefore \chi_{ij,kl}=\dfrac{1}{d}\sum_m\langle k|{E}_m|i\rangle\langle j|{E}_m^\dagger|l\rangle$

> Applying the trace preserving condition, $\sum_m E_m^\dagger E_m=I\implies\sum_m \langle k|E_m^\dagger E_m|i\rangle=\delta_{ik}$, how do we reach\begin{align}
> \sum_j\chi_{ij,kj}&=\delta_{ik}
> \end{align}

Comment: Can you elaborate further on why you think this is the Choi matrix, and not the $\chi$ matrix? It definitely looks like the $\chi$ matrix to me. Also note that $1)$ the $\chi$ matrix depends on what basis $\{E_{i}\}$ you use for the operator space and $2)$ there exists a particular choice of basis $\{E_{i}'\}$ so that the $\chi$ matrix and Choi matrix coincide, namely $\{E'_{i} = E'_{m,n} = |m\rangle \langle n|\}$.

Comment: the trace-preserving condition on a map $\Phi$ translates into its Choi, call it $\sigma$, satisfying $\operatorname{Tr}_2(\sigma)=I$, which is the condition you're referring to. Are you asking why this is the case?

Comment: @JSdJ Thanks for responding. I have edited the post to include "my attempt" section where I tried to understand the particular choice of basis for the Choi matrix to be equal to the $\chi$ matrix. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @JSdJ It looks like $\sum_j\chi_{ij,kj}=\delta_{ik}$ does not require the trace preserving condition ?

Comment: @glS It would be helpful if you could show why that is the case. And as choosing a particular basis equates the Choi matrix and $\chi$ matrix, what we are talking is about showing $\sum_{m,n}\tilde{E}_m^\dagger\tilde{E}_n\chi_{mn}=I\implies Tr(\chi)=1$, right ?

Comment: @SoorajS I don't think I follow. Asking why $\Phi$ trace-preserving implies $\operatorname{tr}_2(J(\Phi))=I$ with $J(\Phi)$ Choi of $\Phi$ is one thing. The equation you write in the last comment doesn't directly involve the Choi, it's how the trace-preserving condition on a quantum map looks like when you represent the map via the $\chi$ matrix, as I also pointed out in the answer to the linked post. Taking the trace and assuming $\tilde E_m$ to be orthonormal you get the condition ${\rm tr}(\chi)=1$ (probably with an extra factor on the RHS though), yes, though I don't see its relevance here

Comment: @glS Since $\mathcal{E}$ is a trace preserving quantum operation, i.e., $\sum_i E_i^\dagger E_i=I$
\begin{align}
\sum_i E_i^\dagger E_i&=\sum_i \sum_m e_{im}^*\tilde{E}_m^\dagger \sum_n e_{in}\tilde{E}_n\\
&=\sum_{m,n}\tilde{E}_m^\dagger\tilde{E}_n\sum_i e_{im}^*e_{in}\\
I&=\sum_{m,n}\tilde{E}_m^\dagger\tilde{E}_n\chi_{mn}\\
\end{align}
I think this is how the equation in my last comment is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Counting the number of free parameters of Choi operators

The number of independent parameters in the $\chi$ matrix is identical to the number of independent parameters in the Choi matrix, or in the channel itself, because these are all isomorphic representations of the same objects.

A map $\Phi$ acting on (the set of linear operators defined on) a Hilbert $H$ is a channel (meaning, it's completely positive and trace-preserving) *iff* its Choi representations, defined as $J(\Phi)\equiv\sum_{ij}\Phi(|i\rangle\!\langle j|)\otimes|i\rangle\!\langle j|$, is positive semidefinite and such that $\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi))=I$.

The set of Hermitian operators on a Hilbert space $H$ is a vector space of (real) dimension $\operatorname{dim}(H)^2$. The set of positive semidefinite operators on a Hilbert space $H$ is a (compact, convex) subset of this space, and thus has the same number of independent parameters.

The set of Choi operators $J(\Phi)$ of channels $\Phi$ is a subset of the set of positive semidefinite operators on $H\otimes H$. It thus has $\dim(H\otimes H)^2=\dim(H)^4$ independent real parameters.
However, the trace-preserving condition removes some of these degrees of freedom. The trace-preserving condition, which reads $\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi))=I$, amounts explicitly to the $\dim(H)^2$ conditions:
$$\sum_i J(\Phi)_{ij,ik}=\delta_{jk}, \qquad \forall j,k=1,...,\dim(H). $$
You can verify that these conditions are linearly independent, and thus remove $\dim(H)^2$ free parameters.
You conclude that the set of Choi operators is a subset of $\operatorname{Lin}(H\otimes H)$ with $\dim(H)^4-\dim(H)^2$ free parameters.

## Reason directly from the $\chi$ representation

You can also just reason directly in terms of the $\chi$ matrix, because $\chi$ and Choi are related via $\chi_{mn}=\langle \tilde E_m|J(\Phi)|\tilde E_n\rangle$, $J(\Phi)=\sum_{mn} \chi_{mn} |\tilde E_m\rangle\!\langle \tilde E_n|$ for some choice of orthonormal operatorial basis $\{\tilde E_m\}$.

I think it's worth showing where some of the relations given in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11814/55) come from though, because the notation can be tricky here. Namely, what exactly the kets and bras in $J(\Phi)=\sum_{mn} \chi_{mn} |\tilde E_m\rangle\!\langle \tilde E_n|$ mean.

I'll somewhat follow the notation in the linked answer, so that the relation between channel/map $\Phi$ and its Choi representation reads
$$\Phi(\rho) = \sum_{m,n} \chi_{m,n} P_m \rho P_n^\dagger.$$
Each $P_m$ is here an operator acting on $H$, and $\{P_m\}$ is a basis for the space of such operators. The Choi representation derived from this decomposition is
$$J(\Phi) = \sum_{ij} \Phi(E_{ij})\otimes E_{ij}
\equiv \sum \chi_{m,n} (P_m E_{ij} P_n^\dagger)\otimes E_{ij}.$$
Consider the action of $J(\Phi)$ on some simple vector $|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\beta\rangle$, which gives
$$J(\Phi)(|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\beta\rangle)=
\sum_{m,n,i} \chi_{m,n} (P_m E_{i,\beta} P_n^\dagger |\alpha\rangle)\otimes |i\rangle \\
= \sum \chi_{m,n} (P_n^\dagger)_{\beta,\alpha} (P_m |i\rangle)\otimes |i\rangle
= \sum \chi_{m,n} (\bar P_n)_{\alpha\beta} (P_m)_{ji} (|j\rangle\otimes |i\rangle).$$
In other words, the action of $J(\Phi)$ on a generic vector $v\in H\otimes H$ can be written as
$$J(\Phi)v=\sum_{m,n} \chi_{m,n}\langle \operatorname{vec}(P_n), v \rangle \operatorname{vec}(P_m),$$
where $\operatorname{vec}(P)$ denotes the *vectorisation* of an operator $P$. Explicitly, if $P:H\to H$, then $\operatorname{vec}(P)\in H\otimes H$ with $\operatorname{vec}(P)_{ij}=P_{ij}$.

The above relation is what we mean when writing $J(\Phi)$ as a sum over ket-bras of a basis of operators.
So, armed with this knowledge, how do we compute $\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi))$ from the expression with the $\chi$ matrix, which is what we want to do to derive what trace-preserving translates into for $\chi$? At the cost of being pedantic, we can start observing that $\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi))$ means explicitly
$$\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi)) = \sum_{\alpha} (\langle\alpha|\otimes I)J(\Phi)(|\alpha\rangle\otimes I)
\equiv \sum_{\alpha\beta\gamma} (\langle\alpha|\otimes\langle\gamma|)J(\Phi)(|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\beta\rangle) \, |\gamma\rangle\!\langle \beta|,$$
and using the expression for $J(\Phi)$ in terms of $\chi_{m,n}$ we get
$$(\langle\alpha|\otimes\langle\gamma|)J(\Phi)(|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\beta\rangle)
= \sum_{m n\alpha\beta\gamma} \chi_{m,n} (\bar P_n)_{\alpha,\beta} (P_m)_{\alpha,\gamma},$$
and therefore
$$\operatorname{tr}_1(J(\Phi)) = 
 \sum \chi_{m,n} P_n^\dagger P_m,$$
hence the trace-preserving condition becoming $\sum_{m,n} \chi_{m,n} P_n^\dagger P_m = I$.